# Header card background color depending on object member

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of objects with different memebers. One of them is the desired background color for the header of a card showing its information like this:

```
$scope.eventsDay19 = [{
    eventTitle: 'Title ',
    eventHour: '21:00',
    eventText: 'Presenter:     <b>John</b>',
    eventPlace: 'Central Park',
    eventIcon: "/img/icon-open.png",
    eventColor: "#fafafa"
}];
```

The eventsDay19 will have a lot of objects thar are presented through:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="card"
         ng-repeat="item in eventsDay19"
         ng-style="{ background: item.eventColor }">

        <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img src={{item.eventIcon}}>
            <h2><b>{{item.eventTitle}}</b></h2>
            <p><b>{{item.eventHour}}</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
            <p ng-bind-html="item.eventText"></p>
            <p>
                <i class="icon ion-map balanced" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.eventPlace}}
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to set the header (or the whole card) in the color specified by `eventColor` member of each object. I have tried with `ng-style` and `ng-class` but no luck yet.

I have tried some posts from StackOverflow with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It gives me a Syntax Error on '-' :-|

Comment: Put single quotes around it. `ng-style="{ 'background-color': item.eventColor }"`

Comment: @kankamuso please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing two things: The first is you should be using 'background-color' instead of background. The second is, you're missing quotes around the attribute.

It should look like this:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in eventsDay19" ng-style="{ 'background-color': item.eventColor }">
```

Comment: Using `background` should be as valid as using `background-color`. It is just a broader style attribute which can specify color, image, positioning etc. on the same line. Futhermore, `background` is a valid unquoted JavaScript property name so there shouldn't be a problem either. I made a working demo [here](http://codepen.io/V-Kopio/pen/AXPGpQ).

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color you have to use 'background-color' instead of 'background'.

Your code should be something like that:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in eventsDay19" ng-style="{'background-color': item.eventColor }">
```

---

**EDIT**

As commented by @V-Kopio

> Using background should be as valid as using background-color. It is just a broader style attribute which can specify color, image, positioning etc. on the same line. Futhermore, background is a valid unquoted JavaScript property name so there shouldn't be a problem either.

The problem was beyond the posted scope.

Comment: No way, it does not change anything. It does not complain on console logs, but the card remains all white :-(

Comment: @kankamuso Thats because #fafafa is white, try changing it to red. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdftsjqs/)

Comment: @kankamuso take a look at this fiddle, maybe it helps. https://jsfiddle.net/mdftsjqs/

Comment: I found it!, I must add the directive on the <div class="item item-avatar" ng-style="{'background-color': item.eventColor }">, not the top card... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Using `background` should be as valid as using `background-color`. It is just a broader style attribute which can specify color, image, positioning etc. on the same line. Futhermore, `background` is a valid unquoted JavaScript property name so there shouldn't be a problem either. I made a working demo [here](http://codepen.io/V-Kopio/pen/AXPGpQ).

Comment: Nice, looks like his problem was beyond the posted scope.